# Sorting Tagsort Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filtering

I am using a filter called tagsort:

[Tagsort](https://wch.io/projects/tagsort/)

Something like [THIS LINK](https://wch.io/static/tagsort/demo-stacks/index.html)

My problem is that all tags are "Random" and I want to have it to be sectioned.

For example:

```
Buildings: Building 1, Building 2, Building 3

City: City 1, City 2, City 3

Type: Type 1, Type 2, Type 3
```

Do you have any idea or maybe another sort plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the plugin options

```
sortAlphabetical: true
```